# Force Jekyll to proccess HTML files without front matter / Add front matter to html using knitr

Tags: html, r-markdown, jekyll, knitr

I'm using RMarkdown to generate a bunch of HTML docs with knitr. Once I upload them to GitHub, it uses Jekyll to render the files to github pages.

What I want is very simple: that the index.html of the repo contains a list of all the pages (.html files) available. Jekyll does that pretty easily with liquid tags (site.html_pages), however it only considers the HTML files that are processed, i.e., the ones with front matter. Knitr doesn't allow me to generate the html with front matter, so jekyll skips them on the analysis, and the site.html_pages gets empty.

I have tried adding "include: '*.html'" on the config file and even creating a plugin to add a front matter to the HTML files, but none of this work.

Is there ANY way to solve this? I can't manually add front matter neither manually change the index.html everytime, it has to be an automated solution.

Comment: Can you access them via [`site.static_files`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. That worked! Thank you very much. Don't know how I skipped that when reading the docs for the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file has no front matter, Jekyll considers it to be a [static file](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/). They are accessible via `site.static_files`, with an object containing `path`, `modified_time`, `name`, `basename`, and `extname`.